# Angularv9 - mat-error: Interpolated string value won't render

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm attempting to implement date validation for matDatepicker and for the most part the error messages do show. The error messages are displayed through interpolation on the variable `raiseError`.

I'm attempting to catch the error case where the start date may be set by the user to be greater than the end date. However, the error messages don't show if the start date is > end date.

My HTML code:

```html
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchEndDate" 
                [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate"
                (dateChange)="validateDates($event)" (dateInput)="defaultErrorMessage()" 
                [matDatepicker]="picker">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
              <mat-error *ngIf="raiseError != null">{{raiseError}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
              <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchEndDate" 
                [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate"
                (dateChange)="validateDates($event)" (dateInput)="defaultErrorMessage()" 
                [matDatepicker]="picker2">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
              <mat-error *ngIf="raiseError != null">{{raiseError}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

The accompanying ts file (See the last else if condition for the location of the problem):

```js
defaultErrorMessage():void {
    console.log('DEFAULTING ERROR MESSAGE')
    this.raiseError = null
  }

  validateDates($event) {
    console.log($event)
    if ($event.value === null){
      this.raiseError = 'The value entered must be a date (MM-DD-YYYY)'
    }
    else if ($event.value < this.minDate){
      this.raiseError = 'You cannot search for results before ' + this.minDate.toLocaleDateString()
    }
    else if ($event.value > this.maxDate){
      this.raiseError = 'You cannot search for results in the future'
    }
    else if (this.searchStartDate > this.searchEndDate) {
      //Even though this statement evaulates to true, it wont show the error message
      // even though the error message for previous if conditions do display
      this.raiseError = 'Search Start Date cannot be after Search End Date'
      console.log(this.raiseError)
    }
    console.log(this.searchStartDate.toLocaleDateString())
    console.log(this.searchEndDate.toLocaleDateString())
  }
```

Thank you for taking a look and for the anticipated help

EDIT:
It's working for issues like this:
[image: When it works]

It's not working for issue when start date > end date:
[image: When it doesn't work]

Comment: I think it'd be easier if you created a stackblitz demo

Comment: I created a stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tfvlc3 and it works fine in there... it just won't render on my project :/ I have no idea why. It's the same code.

Comment: I added some images to illustrate issue^

Comment: The stackblitz demo shows only the default stackblitz demo without any changes.

Comment: what is your min date and max date value ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is working for me, I did hit save so maybe that was it. Please try the link at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tfvlc3 @Paul

Comment: @LogicBlower, the min max date are as follows: ```this.searchEndDate = new Date();
    this.minDate = new Date(this.searchEndDate.getFullYear() - 5, 0, 1);
    this.maxDate = new Date(this.searchEndDate.getFullYear(), this.searchEndDate.getMonth(), ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked a demo on material design and as per my observations:

In material date-picker  as you have min and max date specified , so only that dates will be enabled.

Like your if you set dates

```
 const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
 this.minDate = new Date(currentYear - 5, 0, 1); // 5 years back from current year
 this.maxDate = new Date(currentYear + 1, 11, 31); // 1 year in future
```

So Only dates b/w max and min dates are available to be selected in mat-datepicker.
(from above code as if i check today dates b/w  years 2015 - 2021 dates can be selected)

and as per your logic

```
else if ($event.value < this.minDate){  // value will always be greater than min as you can select from the range. value will always be greater than min date
  this.raiseError = 'You cannot search for results before ' + this.minDate.toLocaleDateString()
}
else if ($event.value > this.maxDate){ // same as value can be selected b/w range value will be less than max date
  this.raiseError = 'You cannot search for results in the future'
}
```

**// value will always be b/w min and max date**

i would suggest you can do  have 2 different min and max for 2 date picker

like if one of the date picker changes,  update the min max of other accordingly.

like if i selected 24 may 2020 as a start date then in other date-picker 24 May 2020 can be a minimum date value and vice versa if i selected end date first then max date of first date picker can be that value

Comment: as specified in the documentation, while the date picker will not allow the user to pick a value greater than or less than the min max date, if you type it in yourself without interfacing with the picker, it will allow you to select a date outside of the picker range. This can also be evidenced by the picture above. I can get all of the different errors to show except for the last else if condition

Comment: so I ended up using your idea of setting the min of picker 2 from the value in picker 1 and now the errors are showing. So I'll just go with that. After using your suggestion, the mat error now works so I guess you have the best answer